# Why is the DOM incomplete after AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-bubbling

I have an AJAX function that populates a page using an on('click')... delegate function and creates 2 or more flex containers each of which has it's own unique id. The id and class is displayed in each flex div block. An outline of the code is shown below:

```
$('li.dicap_menu_action a').on("click",function(){
  var dicap_action =  $(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
    //call to php function that defines the blocks
  });
  return false; //prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

This works fine and output looks like this

[image: Initial blocks created]

Next I wanted to add content to each block based on the id value of the block and then the problems started. As a proof of concept, I created a function called **populate_snapshot** and added the function call to the code below the AJAX function:

```
$('li.dicap_menu_action a').on("click",function(){
    var dicap_action =  $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        //call to php function that defines the blocks
    });
    populate_snapshot();
    return false; //prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

so that it executes directly after the AJAX function to replace the content in each block. The **populate_snapshot** function looks like this

```
function populate_snapshot(){
    var $flx = $('div.dicap-flex-2');
    console.log($flx);
    $flx.each(function() {
        $(this).html('This block was found');
    });
}
```

However, the console log does not find the flex containers and the output does not change when this runs.

If I include an alert() into populate_snapshot as shown, then the function works fine after I dismiss the popup:

```
function populate_snapshot(){
    alert('Test');
    var $flx = $('div.dicap-flex-2');
    console.log($flx);
    $flx.each(function() {
        $(this).html('This block was found');
    });
}
```

the console log shows the 2 flex containers and output becomes

[image: Populates OK after alert function]

It is as though the DOM needs to be refreshed before the populate_snapshot function can run. Is there some way to do this or is there something more fundamental that I am missing. Is this an event-bubbling issue? and Is there some other way to delegate the populate_snapshot function so that it runs automatically after completion of the AJAX call?

I thought about using ajaxComplete() after the AJAX to trigger populate_snapshot, but this will not work because my populate_snapshot will later use another AJAX function and this will result in an endless loop.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: That's the asynchronous part in AJAX -> [Ajax | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: Execute `populate_snapshot()` in the `success` handler (or use `.then()`) of the `$.ajax()` call

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, unfortunately I have to run populate_snapshot as a separate script and it has to run after the AJAX completes in this application and cannot be part of the AJAX.Effectively, I create the blocks and then I need some way to trigger a separate script to add html to the div blocks. Is there some trigger that can run after the AJAX that will recognize the changes to the DOM? or some way to refresh the DOM before running the second script.

Comment: @Andreas, you solved the problem, I hadn't fully understood your answer. The .then() call was exactly what I needed. I will add the solution below for anyone who needs more detail.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andreas for his advice - this answer is totally to his credit.

Here is how I used this advice to solve my problem. The AJAX part of the code was changed as follows (notice the .then() function):

```
$('li.dicap_menu_action a').on("click",function(){
    var dicap_action =  $(this).attr("href");
    var aj = $.ajax({
        //call to php function that defines the blocks
    });
    aj.then(function(){
      populate_snapshot();
    })
    return false; //prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

The populate_snapshot function is:

```
function populate_snapshot(){
    var $flx = $('div.dicap-flex-2');
    console.log($flx);
    $flx.each(function() {
        $(this).html('This block was found');
    });
}
```

and the proof of concept output is as expected

[image: Working output]

Again, thanks and all quedos to @Andreas.